# Theming a file link by adding custom file name suggestions

Tags: theming, files

I want to display a bunch of data inside a view table, where each dataset has up to three different files. The user should be able to download these files by clicking a custom button or image in this table. I already learned that it's really hard or impossible to create different templates for fields of type file (file_link), at least without creating custom modules. For example, one file is from type PDF, and by default, Drupal shows a small PDF icon in front of the file name, and the file size behind. I can completely customize this behavior by editing `file-link.html.twig`, but this customizes ALL file links in the table, well, on the entire page.

I want to create a custom template for each file, based on their field name, like this: `file-link--field--node--field-xyz-pdf.html.twig`. I tried to alter theme suggestiongs by hooking into `MYMODULE_theme_suggestions_file_link_alter(&$suggestions, $variables)` through a custom module, but `$variables` doesn't contain the original field name or something else unique related to the field.

My next step was trying to hook into `MYMODULE_preprocess_file_link(&$variables)` and further into `MYMODULE_preprocess_views_view_field(&$variables, $hook)`, finally finding the field name: `$variables['field']->field`.

But how do I pass this field name back to the theme suggestions hook? Honestly, I'm at my wits' end.

Comment: You'll want to use "getters" or "magic" methods to get the fields into your custom theme hook. For example, you can do something like this in your hook: `if ($node->hasField('field_foo') && !$node->get('field_foo')->isEmpty())`. You'd need to define and check for a node around that as well. Once you are within that code, you should be able to get many more variables to use as part of your template naming convention.